match case instruction with wildcard
I'm trying to write a match/case instruction with wildcard or pattern matching. Something like that :
match 'foo' : 
    case 'fo*'  : print (1)
    case 'bar'  : print (2)
    case 'foo'  : print (3)

These lines prints 3. I want it to print 1. Is it possible to use a wildcard or a full regular expression in a case statement?

You might find this SO question of interest link
